# AWS Amplify / CDK: Updating existing SES Email Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, amazon-ses

I created a custom resource in my amplify project for an SES template we use.

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
...

    const templateHtml = readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './template.html')).toString();
    const templateTxt = readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './template.txt')).toString();

    const cfnTemplate = new ses.CfnTemplate(this, 'TemplateID', {
      template: {
        templateName: 'TemplateName',
        subjectPart: 'Email subject',

        htmlPart: templateHtml,
        textPart: templateTxt,
      }
    });
```

I'm realizing now that updating the HTML file that is the source doesn't update the CDK, so it doesn't attempt to do anything with the template.

Then I tried changing the "TemplateID" to something like "TemplateIDv1", but that broke as well because ... well, it's not a good idea to change the ID after creating the resource...

The only remaining idea I have is to change this custom resource to use CDK 2, which adds a `tags` property that might allow me to change something on the resource to trigger an update...

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like CDK 2 isn't supported (without headaches), so that idea's out: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm realizing now that updating the HTML file that is the source doesn't update the CDK

That is not the exepected behaviour. If you modify `htmlPart`, `textPart`, or `subjectPart`, your SES template will [update without interruption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ses-template-template.html) when you deploy your Stack.

> it's not a good idea to change the ID after creating the resource...

Indeed. This is unnecessary and will result in resource replacement.

> Any ideas?

The problem will be with your implementation, perhaps how the string is being loaded from the file. Find the CloudFormation JSON template artefact that CDK outputs to `cdk.out`. The template's `AWS::SES::Template` resource will change when your code is properly modifying a "part" attribute.  Make a change, run `cdk synth` and look for diffs.  A changed template will trigger a resource update on deploy.

Comment: I updated the code above to show how I'm pulling in the htmlPart. Should I be doing this a different way? updating the HTML file definitely doesn't update the template...

Comment: @Ryan  The code looks fine.  Not sure what "template" you mean.  In any case, stick with the Cfn Template JSON for now.  What's the (string) value of `"HtmlPart"` under the `AWS::SES::Template` Resource (a) before you make a change to the html file and (b) after you make a change, save it, and run `cdk synth`?  We expect the local Cfn Template to have changed.

Comment: @Ryan Also verify the account/region you are deploying to is the same one you are checking.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found the problem. I have an npm script that is supposed to run before the build process (e.g. named `amplify:CustomEmailTemplate`) which copies the template to deploy to the build directory. It doesn't look like it's running -- so the old template was still there. I ran it manually and then ran the build and the CloudFormation template now includes the latest version of the HTML. Appreciate the help.